# Is there any way to cast needed class object to another at runtime without direct cast in .net?

Tags: .net, object, casting, runtime

For example, i have this:

```
class BasePacket
{
   int header;
   int type;
}

class ChildPacket1 : BasePacket
{
   //...
}

class ChildPacket2 : BasePacket
{
   //...
}

BasePacket bp;
Type t;
object obj = CreateNeededChildPacket(out t); //return one of childs as object and it's real type
bp = ...// anyway to cast obj to type represented by t? or by using something else?
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd give more context. If you know the type of `i` beforehand, where does `t` come up? It wouldn't make sense for `t` to be any type other than `int`, would it?

Comment: sure t can be any type. even more, for me it would be handmade types, not native .net types. and even more - i itself should be handmade type

Comment: So how would you expect that conversion to be handled, if you're trying to assign to an `int` variable, but `t` is `MyCustomType`?

Comment: that was just an example of conversion i need. in my case, i is parent class and i need to assign value of child class, that i don't know at compilation process

Comment: And what code would you expect to be invoked to perform the conversion? Basically your question is unanswerable at the moment - the example you've given isn't representative, and there are far too many unknowns in what you *are* trying to do.

Comment: sorry, i will edit it to give more sense

Comment: I know I'm in good company, but can I clarify do you want to have VB.Net's implicit casting support in C#?

Comment: uhh i think i just made it all hard and confused you all. I think i found the solution, just in my case it not that simple. i have templates that return needed objects and etc %) and i don't know about VB implicit casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are creating one of two derived classes and storing it in a base variable...this does not require any casting at all as it is perfectly fine to do this per the laws of inheritance. A base-type variable can always be assigned a more derived object since anything the base class would be able to do it is guaranteed the derived class can do as well, so it is safe. For example, a Math teacher can perform any action a regular Teacher can (such as GradePapers()). It would be safe to point a Math Teacher object with a Teacher variable.

```
BasePacket bp = (BasePacket) CreateNeededChildPacket();
```

---

**Edit:**
In response to your comment, Ideally you would have the CreateNeededChildPacket() method return a BasePacket type (if the returned object is always dervied from BasePacket). Just as a base parameter can accept a derived object, a base return type can return a derived object, this is the beauty of inheritance. This would be much safer for someone down the road calling your method.

```
BasePacket CreateNeededChildPacket() 
{
    // do something
    return AnyObjectThatDerivesFromBasePacket;    
}
```

---

If you cannot update the method then you could add some additional type-checking just to be safe.

```
object obj = CreateNeededChildPacket();
BasePacket bp = null;

if (obj is BasePacket) 
   bp = (BasePacket) obj;
else
   throw new Exception("Object was not a valid BasePacket type: " + obj.GetType.ToString());
```

Comment: CreateNeededChildPacket return object type, not child class object

Comment: You can cast the returned object to a BasePacket.

Answer (score 4):

[Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) can handle a wide range of type conversion scenarios, including this one, very efficiently, subject to the following:

> The reader must understand that Convert.ChangeType() works only for
>   certain, standard .NET system types.  It does not work for any
>   component that does not implement IConvertible, and it does not work
>   for custom types.

```
float f = 1.1f;
int i;
Type t = typeof(int);
i = (int)Convert.ChangeType(f, t);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Note that in your specific example, converting between two value types, `ChangeType` will not be as efficient as a direct cast because `ChangeType` returns the integer value boxed as an object.

You can use `ChangeType` with your own classes if they implement `IConvertable`, e.g.

```
public class MyClass : IConvertible
{
    public float MyFloatValue { get; set; }

    int IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return (int)MyFloatValue;
    }

    // TODO: Implement the rest of IConvertable
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass() { MyFloatValue = 42.42f };
i = (int) Convert.ChangeType(myClass, t);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: your answer is good, but not for my case. because i did confuse everyone in the begining. it can be used to convert to int (IConvertible.ToInt32), but not to BasePacket :(